# structure.sql file is modified on running migrations, things are added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

After running 'rails db:migrate' my structure file is modified in a way that is different then my coworkers. for example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.foo_bar_seq
  + AS integer --<< this is added.
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE


- WHERE sometime > ((('now'::text)::date - '3 mons'::interval) - '8 days'::interval))
+ WHERE sometime > ((CURRENT_DATE - '3 mons'::interval) - '8 days'::interval)) -- becomes this
```

I can't figure it out and is highly annoying as I have to commit by line changes to my structure file whenever I add a migration. We are all using the same version of psql 11.2.

Comment: Hi Chris. Assuming you're on development environment, what I would try first is to recreate the database using `rake db:drop db:create db:structure:load`. That will

Comment: Hi tom, I was hoping to avoid that as it takes about 6-7 hours to restore, So you think that will reset it, but to what?

Comment: Could you check if the versions of all dependencies matches? And also check the version of Ruby.

Comment: @Ferrybig the extensions match.Ruby matches.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes different versions of postgresql running on your local machine changes the structure as well.